# Deconstruct an variable containing integers into an array

Tags: php, moodle

I am fairly new to PHP and i appear to have reached a roadblock in my code.I have a variable which contains a sequence of numbers separated by a space. I intend on submitting each number into the database as an individual record. My question is how can i deconstruct the variable into individual integers with the intention of submitting each integer as a new record. Here is my code:

```
foreach ($domains as $domain)
{         
    $clicked_domains = array($form_entry->{"domain_$domain->id"});         

    if($clicked_domains){

        foreach($clicked_domains as $final_selection){
            if ($final_selection != 0){
             echo  $final_selection." "; // $final_selection now has the value of  17 20 12
            }
        }
    }  
 }
```

I would now like to extract each integer from $final_selection (excluding the spaces) for submission to the DB

Comment: Have you tried to [explode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but it seems to me that your `$final_selection` variable does not contain a "sequence of numbers". It only contains one number at a time, you are just echoing those numbers as a sequence. This means that you can put your submission logic in the second `if` statement, without the need to deconstruct the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to create an array of integers, and then just loop through each one.

```
$integer_array = explode(" ", $final_selection);

foreach($integer_array as $integer) {
    //submit $integer
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

Check out [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

> Returns an array of strings, each of which is a substring of string formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the string delimiter.